# How do I make it so that when I press my mouse the code in it doesn't slow down? Python

Tags: python-3.x, input, mouselistener

I'm trying to make a program that runs in the background that plays a sound file whenever you press the mouse button down but in doing so I've been running into the issue that my mouse slows down.

My code:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import winsound

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    winsound.PlaySound("tom", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
    
with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what exactly you mean by "mouse slows down"? Does this happen if you click a single time, or if you hold the mouse button down?

Comment: it happens if I just click a single time